# ASP.Net Core (MVC6) Unable to login with seeded users

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is how I did it.

```cs
public class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        var user0 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "bob", Email = "bob@asd.com" };
        var result = userManager.CreateAsync(user0, "Password1!").Result;

    }
}
```

The initialize method is run in Startup.cs in the Configure method at the very end:

```cs
SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
```

When I look at the database, the users are there as expected. When I try to login though, I get an invalid login attempt. When I try to Register the user with the same email address, it doesn't detect a duplicate entry and adds a new user with the same address.

UserManager seems to behave differently in the context of a Controller. How would I be able to create seed users properly so I can login with them?

```cs
Id  AccessFailedCount   ConcurrencyStamp    Email   EmailConfirmed  LockoutEnabled  LockoutEnd  NormalizedEmail NormalizedUserName  PasswordHash    PhoneNumber PhoneNumberConfirmed    SecurityStamp   TwoFactorEnabled    UserName
e3ff23eb-5db9-4eb3-871e-e95232178e1c    0   241c36e0-b0a9-4c86-af98-6d38132947e9    bob@asd.com 0   1   NULL    BOB@ASD.COM BOB AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAECFF4uxt8kT3nZgU9nhfticduyI3OXAxCZg+XJT/0Id280Tgf6B9cCY+Il6beRTFWw==    NULL    0   3e9a2185-d248-4589-aa30-ecbb145787ff    0   bob
```

Comment: I think the unique key is the username and not email ... Did you try to make the user with the same username ?

Comment: The unique key is the ApplicationUserId column. The UserManager does the check for a duplicate, the database allows it. But I did try to make the user with the same username and it still registers it, and I see the duplicate record in the database. If I try a second time (through the controller action) a third record will not be created and I get a validation error saying (that username/email already exists)

Comment: On my end the username is always the full email. Does the controller possibly use the full email and you don't (bob vs bob@asd.com for username )?

Comment: Nope, I tried with the full email and same issue.

Comment: Just for giggles, post the raw result of a select * statement on your data.

Comment: Added, kinda hard to see it properly

Answer (score 3):

I have just encountered with this problem.

as the following code

```
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetService>();
    ApplicationUser user0, user1;
    if (context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "nemo@mail.com"))
        user0 = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == "nemo@mail.com");
    else
    {
        user0 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "nemo@mail.com", Email = "nemo@mail.com" };
        var result = userManager.CreateAsync(user0, "Abc123").Result;
    }
    if (context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "teresa@mail.com"))
        user1 = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == "teresa@mail.com");
    else
    {
        user1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "teresa@mail.com", Email = "teresa@mail.com" };
        var result = userManager.CreateAsync(user1, "Abc123").Result;
    }
```

When I login with "teresa@mail.com" the login will reject by message "Invalid login attempt.".

But with the "nemo@mail.com" the login will success.

As the result, ASP.net seems to use UserName & password for login verification.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that "email address as username" has been mentioned in comments but I'm posting this answer for anyone experiencing the same symptoms. I found that when seeding the database with a user that had a different username and email address, I could not log in as that user. Registering a new user on the site worked fine and I could login as a user that I'd registered. Looking in the database at the seeded user and the registered user I saw that the difference was that the registered user has its email address as its username.

So yes, an application built on the Visual Studio template has an assumption that you want to us email addresses as usernames. Look at the AccountController class -> `Login` Action Method (POST). It calls `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` with the first argument as `model.Email`. Hover your mouse over that method or right-click go to definition and you'll see that the first argument is expected to be `string userName`.

So you have two options:

1. Modify the controller, view and viewmodel involved with logon to allow user to enter a username at logon.
2. Use email address as username when seeding users into the database.